# Start date and End Date and one day of week like Monday

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I will give you Start date and End Date   and one day of week like Monday

```
Public void check(string StartDate, string EndDate, String Monday
{
    // Logic here
}
```

How to find that  how many monday from start date to end date and which date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your goal you should pass the startDate, endDate and a day of week (prefferably not as string but as a DayOfWeek for a better code-readability):

```
public List<DateTime> GetListOfDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    var list = new List<DateTime>(); 
    var daysDifference = endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays;
    for (int i = 0; i < daysDifference; i++)
    {
        var date = startDate.AddDays(i); 
        if (date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
        {
            list.Add(date); 
        }
    }
    return list; 
}
```

The returned list will contain all the Mondays (in case you passed `Monday` as a `dayOfWeek`) with their exact dates. If you execute `.Count()` on the returned list you can see how many of them were returned.

Comment: @NayeemMansoori I posted a code which works without loops. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CountMondays(DateTime start, DateTime end){
    int mondays = 0;
    for(DateTime date = start;date <= end; date=date.AddDays(1)){
        if(date.DateOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            mondays++;
    }
    return mondays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work and does NOT require a loop. The difference in speed is not much. For around 100 years its 5ms, however, for 2000 years, it's around 60-70ms (using the List sort above) where the non-looped is always at 0.

```
public static int GetAmountBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    int addAmount = 0;
    switch (dayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            addAmount = 0;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            addAmount = 1;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            addAmount = 2;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            addAmount = 3;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            addAmount = 4;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            addAmount = 5;
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            addAmount = 6;
            break;
    }

    return (endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + addAmount) / 7; 

}
```